# Automatically map tag:japanese to tag:japanese-cuisine for new users

Tags: discussion, tags

For new users, it would be easier if they can just type "japanese" to stand for "japanese-cuisine". New users can't create new tags, and rather than having them not tag the type of cuisine, a bit of automation can help. (For seasoned users, those two tags would be synonyms anyway.)

Comment: We certainly can create [tag synonyms](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), but generally only do this when there's evidence of an ongoing problem (e.g. two tags which are nearly identical and are both frequently-used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the tag autocompleter begins matching at `japa` I don't think this is really necessary, is it?

[image: tag completion at 'japa']

What I mean is, nobody actually needs to *type* "japanese-cuisine", they can just type "japa" and use their mouse to select or press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> to select.